# Function to add more values to variable

Tags: javascript, select

I got the following code, and i want to have my i variable to be read by the select value and then every time i change the select value add the new value to the older one, but i dont know why it doesnt work

```js
var tamany = document.getElementById('tam');
var i = document.getElementById('tam').value
var ancho = "300";
var largo = "300px";
var cc = parseInt(ancho) + parseInt(i);

function aa() {
document.getElementById("change").style.width = (cc + '+px+');
document.getElementById("change").style.height = (largo);
})
```

```css
ul {
  margin-top: -700px;
}
#man {
  z-index: 500;
}
#pantalon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left: -500px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#change {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="man" src="man.png" height="900">
<img id="pantalon" src="http://static.bershka.net/4/photos2/2015/I/0/2/p/5337/506/594/5337506594_1_2_4.jpg?t=ts" height="500">
<img id="change" src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2015/I/0/2/p/9592/500/800/9592500800_2_1_1.jpg?timestamp=1437741171705" height="500" width="500">
<button onclick="aa()">Cambiar</button>

<select id="tam" name="tam1">
  <option value="none"></option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">-100</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is your CSS and container HTML necessary?

Comment: no,just javascript but i posted it for more information i case someone asked

Comment: You have an extra `)` after the `aa` function, that's causing a syntax error in the Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

One, you're setting `i` and `cc` when the page loads. You need to set them in `aa()` so they get the current selection from the menu.

Second, you were concatenating `'+px+'` to `cc` instead of just `px`, which created an invalid width.

Third, you had an extra `)` after the `aa()` function.

```js
var tamany = document.getElementById('tam');
var ancho = "300";
var largo = "300px";

function aa() {
  var i = tamany.value
  var cc = parseInt(ancho) + parseInt(i);
  document.getElementById("change").style.width = (cc + 'px');
  document.getElementById("change").style.height = (largo);
}
```

```css
ul {
  margin-top: -700px;
}
#man {
  z-index: 500;
}
#pantalon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left: -500px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#change {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="man" src="man.png" height="900">
<img id="pantalon" src="http://static.bershka.net/4/photos2/2015/I/0/2/p/5337/506/594/5337506594_1_2_4.jpg?t=ts" height="500">
<img id="change" src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2015/I/0/2/p/9592/500/800/9592500800_2_1_1.jpg?timestamp=1437741171705" height="500" width="500">
<button onclick="aa()">Cambiar</button>

<select id="tam" name="tam1">
  <option value="none"></option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">-100</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, now work as I wish thanks, sorry for the mess but im pretty new on this

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = tamany.options[tamany.selectedIndex].value;
```

That is how you get the value of the selected option. To update the `i` variable when the user chooses an option, use the `onchange` event.

Comment: And then i should add my i increaser under the first line of the function right?

Comment: `tamany.value` should work fine, you don't need to do the indexing into options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an `onchange()` event, this means that every time the value of the drop down list is changed, this function gets triggered so you can add the new value to the older ones.

Comment: That's only one part of the story. In order to get the actual value of the selected option, read my answer.